How to force scripted chart.js element color changes to persist, rather than immediately revert to default values
I am creating a bubble graph plotting each bubble as a separate dataset. An event handler displays additional information about each dataset when the corresponding point is clicked on. The display is set to display information about up to two points at a time to allow a side-by-side comparison.
The function that runs onClick is able to temporarily change the border and background color for that point, however the colors seem to revert back to their defaults when the chart element ceases being active. This is a problem because I want these colors to indicate which points are being compared, and I would like the scripted color change to persist.
Here's the function that configures the chart, including defining the onClick function and limiting the event handler to mouse clicks:
const config = {
   type: 'bubble',
   data: data,
   options: {
      events: ['click'],
      responsive: true,
      plugins: {
      //setting the legend, title and tooltip plugin options; omitted for brevity
      },
   onClick: function(e){
      var element - myChart.getElementsAtEventForMode(e, 'nearest', {intersect: true},true);
      if (element.length > 0){
         cluster=element[0]
         idx=cluster.datasetIndex; //which of N bubbles has been clicked on 
         cluster.element.options.backgroundColor="#3376699ff"
         cluster.element.options.borderColor="#ff0000"
         var info=document.getElementByClassName("details")
         show_details(info, idx) //display the info DIV that goes with that point
      }
   },
};


To my chagrin, the border color goes right back to the default rgba(0,0,0,0.1) and the bubble color also reverts to the default immediately after clicking (unless I click on it a second time, in which case the color change persists until I click anywhere else). I've turned off other event handlers in an attempt to solve the problem, but that didn't work (I had thought that perhaps the mouse hover was overriding my color change).

This question is similar to: ChartJS v2 - Keep tooltip open when user click on a point of a multiple lines chart. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please provide a [mre]; it is very unlikely that anybody could know for instance what object cluster.element points to, without running the code.
